# Offload compilation through SSH?

Tags: ssh, arch-linux, compiling, gentoo, cross-compilation

I have a hacked up Chromebook on which I'm running Gentoo. When I try to compile *anything*, CPU usage spikes up to 100%, the temperature increases by ~10 degrees C, battery usage spikes (4.X W -> 10 W), and it's a slow process. But I also have an Arch Linux computer running, and I can connect to it over SSH. They are both x86_64 CPUs. Is there any way I could offload the compilation of stuff (Linux kernel, everyday packages, etc.) onto the Arch Linux machine over SSH? I haven't done anything like this before. Might cross-compilation be necessary?

Comment: Maybe `distcc` is a transparent solution...

Comment: Yes, `distcc` _may_ work, but since the two machines run different setups, it may not work smoothly (different versions of development packages installed, etc.)

Comment: ErikF's answer is a nice addition when you are already doing package caching for other distributions you may be using. The overhead of maintaining several setups of this kind however comes with a high maintenance burden. Gentoo, Arch, Linux from Scratch, Openwrt and other projects are great for learning (I recommend Arch to every new co-worker) but not always the best fit. It's particularly not ideal for machines primarily built as consumption devices like Chromebooks are. I'm surprised that they can cope this well with regular Linux installs while being built as image-based appliances.

Comment: @yeti Distcc works beautifully! Thank you so much!

Comment: @Kusalananda – `distcc` only needs "similar enough" `gcc`s. Linking is not distributed, so mismatching libraries won't hurt.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you don't have to cross-compile (that would be necessary if you targeted another architecture.) There are two ways that I can think of that you could set up your systems to do this:

1. Use `distcc`. The [Gentoo](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Distcc) and [Arch wikis](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Distcc) do a good job of describing how to install and configure the program, so I won't copy the entire thing here. Briefly, you need to have the following set up in order for it to work:

   - Your `CFLAGS` in `/etc/portage/make.conf` *must not* use `march=native` or `mtune=native`, because the remote computer will use its idea of "native" CPU, not the local computer's. If you're using "native", find out which flags to use [by running:](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Distcc#CFLAGS_and_CXXFLAGS)

     ```
     $ gcc -v -E -x c -march=native -mtune=native - < /dev/null 2>&1 | grep cc1 | perl -pe 's/^.* - //g;'
     ```
   - Both computers need the same compiler and binutils versions.
   - Both computers need `distcc` installed, configured and running.
2. Use a `chroot` environment on your Arch system with a copy of your Chromebook filesystem (treat this like you're doing an installation of Gentoo, so copy `resolv.conf` from your Arch installation, and mount the appropriate filesystems inside per [the Gentoo installation manual](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Handbook:AMD64/Installation/Base), keeping in mind the warning about `/dev/shm` if Arch's version is a symlink.) It needs to be as close as possible to your Chromebook environment, or else you'll end up with possibly incorrect binaries; if you do a copy, you'll have to rebuild less packages. Inside of this environment:

   - Add `FEATURES="buildpkg"` to `/etc/portage/make.conf`.
   - The generated packages will then be in `/usr/portage/packages`. You can also compile the kernel in this way and simply copy the generated kernel and appropriate `/lib/modules` directory to the Chromebook. (Remember that these directory locations are relative to the chroot!) The wiki recommends having an NFS mount or other server so that you don't have to copy files manually: this can be set up on the Arch system proper. I like setting up `rsyncd` for this purpose, but use whatever method you prefer for file access.

   On your Chromebook:

   - Make sure to add `FEATURES="getbinpkg"` to `/etc/portage/make.conf` if you want to prevent it from compiling locally.
   - If you're using remote file access, add `PORTAGE_BINHOST="protocol://path/to/your/chroot/usr/portage/packages"` to `/etc/portage/make.conf`.

   Refer to the [Binary package guide in the Gentoo wiki](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Binary_package_guide) for more information.

I have done both of these methods in the past, and they both work pretty well. My observations on the two methods:

1. `distcc` is finicky to get working, even if you have identical setups on both sides. Keeping `gcc` and `binutils` versions the same will be your biggest challenge. Once you get it going, however, it's pretty fast, and if you have extra computers that are fast enough you can add them.
2. The `chroot` environment is less finicky, but if you make changes to any part of the portage environment (`CFLAGS`, `USE` flags, masks, profiles, etc.) you have to make sure that both sides stay consistent, or else you can end up with packages that have the wrong dependencies. Gentoo is pretty good about making sure the USE flags match, but it doesn't track compiler options in binary packages. One advantage is that you're not limited by the (lack of) disk space and memory on the Chromebook for compilation.

If you're going to use the `chroot` method, I would make a script to do all the uninteresting work required in setting it up (replace `/mnt/gentoo` with your chroot location):

```
cp -L /etc/resolv.conf /mnt/gentoo/etc
mount -t proc proc /mnt/gentoo/proc
mount --rbind /sys /mnt/gentoo/sys
mount --make-rslave /mnt/gentoo/sys
mount --rbind /dev /mnt/gentoo/dev
mount --make-rslave /mnt/gentoo/dev
chroot /mnt/gentoo /bin/bash
umount -R /mnt/gentoo/dev
umount -R /mnt/gentoo/sys
umount /mnt/gentoo/proc
```

Comment: That's a great answer, but I have one question: The OP mentioned SSH probably for security reasons. I couldn't find anything about how distcc works under this aspect, it looks like you set it up at home or your lab and hope that nobody is going to mess with it on your network. Is that correct or could one also use distcc remotely to fetch, compile and install updates securely from home when you are on the go?

Comment: @LiveWireBT you can set `distcc` to work over SSH (https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Distcc#SSH_for_communication), with some extra work involved. I wouldn't recommend compiling over the Internet (it's almost certainly *way* slower than even the slowest computer!) but you can do it.

Comment: I forgot to mention that `march=native` can't be used in a chroot for the same reason that it can't be used with `distcc`: the source and target machines almost certainly don't have the same CPU model.

Comment: I tried `distcc`ing between two PIs and an AMD64 notebook which had an arm-gcc installed and even that worked. The only problem I had was related to IPv6 and was from PI to PI. Distributed jobs from PI to AMD64 worked fine. I will retry that when Devuan for the PIs has settled down a bit more. Lots of fun! \o/

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by the accepted answer, but too much for a comment:

On the **chromebook**, to isolate the root filsystem from system mount points `/dev`, `/sys`, `/run` etc.:

```
mount -o bind / /mnt/gentoo
# If neccesary
mount -o bind /boot /mnt/gentoo/boot
mount -o bind /usr /mnt/gentoo/usr
```

In `/etc/exports`:
    /mnt/gentoo 192.168.0.2(rw,sync,nohide,no_root_squash)

Make sure there is kernel support for exporting over NFS. And start the relevant services. (`nfsd`)

On the **Arch linux** box, `/etc/fstab`:

```
# You might need to tune mount options for performance.
192.168.0.3:/mnt/gentoo   /mnt/gentoo   nfs   defaults 0 0
```

Make sure the correct service is started on the Arch side (`netmount` or `nfs`). Check if the remote filesystem has successfully mounted.

Gracefully stolen from ErikF (don't copy `resolv.conf`, since the running system should already have it):

> ```
> mount -t proc proc /mnt/gentoo/proc
> mount --rbind /sys /mnt/gentoo/sys
> mount --make-rslave /mnt/gentoo/sys
> mount --rbind /dev /mnt/gentoo/dev
> mount --make-rslave /mnt/gentoo/dev
> chroot /mnt/gentoo /bin/bash
> umount -R /mnt/gentoo/dev
> umount -R /mnt/gentoo/sys
> umount /mnt/gentoo/proc
> ```

Make sure `/etc/portage/make.conf` has a correct `-march` setting, not `native`!

Now, run `emerge` to your liking and everything is installed directly into the rootfs of the chromebook.

**Important note:** I've added this answer as a possibility that seems fun. It has not been tested. Also, exporting the root filesystem (rw, no_root_squash) will give the creeps to any guy that respects IT security. So only do this on a very trusted network!